# ChartJS - Finding the minimum and maximum labels that are inside a pan (When zooming)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart like this:

[image: pan]

Now I need to find the minimum and maximum labels that are inside a pan, when I zoom, for example:

[image: pan complete]

The minimum would be `2018-07-16`, and the maximum would be `2018-11-3`.

For *panning,* I'm using this attribute:

```
pan: {
    enabled: true,
    mode: 'x',
    onPanComplete: function(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

If I look at the returned object, I see a lot of information about this pan. But I can't find relevant information to conclude these extremum labels.

I thought the attribute `chartArea` would be sufficient, but its value doesn't differ for two very different pans. Same goes for `config`, `boxes`, and a lot of other attributes.

How can I find these extremum labels?

Comment: Do you have a code sample?

Comment: @KalimahApps I should've provided my own, but the code in [timclutton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615816/6282576) is sufficient. In his example, if I were to pan over the labels `g` and `h`, I want to be able to find exactly these two labels, `g` and `h`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using [chartjs-plugin-zoom](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom) for this.

Digging around in the `chart` object passed to the `onPanComplete` function reveals that the `scales` property is updated to achieve the zoom'n'pan functionality. Knowing this, it's fairly trivial to retrieve the first and last tick objects which contain the `label` property you're looking for.

Below is a snippet that demonstrates accessing the ticks via `onPanComplete` and outputting them to the page:

```js
let ft = document.getElementById("ft"),
  lt = document.getElementById("lt");

new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 'c',
          max: 'h'
        }
      }]
    },
    plugins: {
      zoom: {
        pan: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'x',
          onPanComplete: function({
            chart
          }) {
            let ticks = chart.scales["x-axis-0"]._ticks;
            ft.innerText = JSON.stringify(ticks[0]);
            lt.innerText = JSON.stringify(ticks[ticks.length - 1]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.1"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@0.7.4"></script>
<canvas id="chart" style="max-height:125px"></canvas>
<p>
  First tick: <span id="ft"></span><br>Last tick: <span id="lt"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: `scales['x-axis-0']._ticks` returns *all* the labels and it seems to be independent of the pan. So in your example, no matter where on the chart I pan, the first tick is always `a` and the last tick is always `j`. I tested it on my own chart and the result is the same, I can't seem to be able to conclude the location of the pan (by determining the first and last tick).

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani What you describe is not what I see. If I zoom in (I use the mousewheel), then pan, the first and last visible ticks are outputted. Which browser (name/version) are you using? Can you add a GIF or screenshots of the behaviour you see?

Comment: To clarify my last comment, [here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj4X0.png) of the snippet after zooming in and panning. "First tick:" and "Last tick:" match the chart.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to show it with a GIF or a screenshot, because I use a different method for panning; I use drag and drop, I click on the chart (left click), hold it, move it to another part of the chart, and then release the left click. I guess I should've mentioned it in the question, but I thought that's the difference between panning and zooming (zooming being the use of mouse-wheel and panning being the use of drag-and-drop). With this way of panning, it doesn't actually zoom, but the event is fired and the first and last ticks are shown.

Comment: Ok, that's exactly how I pan as well. That's what I meant with "... zoom in (I use the mousewheel), then pan,...". It's just that you need to zoom in first with my example chart to actually see any panning happening.

Comment: Are you really seeing a different result to the screenshot I posted in my comment?

Comment: If I zoom in first (using the two-finger method on my laptop's touch-pad) and then pan (using drag-and-drop), then it works and I can recreate the screenshot you posted. However, this is *two steps* for a simple zoom. Isn't it possible to do this exact thing with just the drag-and-drop way of zooming? So that there wouldn't be need for a zoom (either two-finger or mouse-wheel). Because again, I thought `zoom` is for `{two-finger, mouse-wheel}` and `pan` is for `{drag-and-drop}`.

Comment: Yes, of course it is. This is just a demo. I don't know how your chart is configured since you've not provided code, but I've updated my example to set `ticks.max` and `.min` so that zooming is no longer required to pan.

Comment: If you want to see the first and last tick when you *zoom* then simply use the same code from my example in the `onZoomComplete` callback.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this solves it. And excuse me for my incomplete question. I'll make sure to provide a reproducible example next time.

Comment: Great! I'm glad we got there in the end. Good luck with the rest of your coding!