# How do I get the min/max axis values in Chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

I'd like to get the minimum and maximum values of the axes on a Chart.js 4.4.0 plot.  When the plot is created, these values must be calculated somewhere.  However, reading through the [Chart.js docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/), there don't seem to be any options for accessing them.

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58644695/chart-js-how-to-get-min-max-values-of-x-axis) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58352678/chartjs-finding-the-minimum-and-maximum-labels-that-are-inside-a-pan-when-zoo) Stack Overflow questions are similar, but they're specific to using the `chartjs-plugin-zoom` plugin, which I'm not using.  Furthermore, the approach employed by the answer involves finding minimum and maximum tick values, which is not what I want.  For instance, a graph may have ticks at every integer, but the right boundary of the plot might naturally fall at, say, x=10.5.  I want to find the actual boundary of the plot at 10.5, not the maximum tick at 10.

In Flot.js, this was done trivially as

```
xmin = plot.getAxes().xaxis.min;
xmax = plot.getAxes().xaxis.max;
```

Is this possible to do in Chart.js, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `chart` is your chart instance, i.e., the result, `const chart = new Chart(....)` then you can access the scales by their `id`, through
[`chart.scales`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/classes/Chart.html#scales)

Once you have the scale object, the properties you're looking for are
[`min`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/classes/Scale.html#min)
and [`max`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/classes/Scale.html#max).

So, for the default x axis, it would be:

```js
const {min: xMin, max: xMax} = chart.scales.x;
```

Even if you don't save the result of `new Chart`, the chart instance is almost always accessible through the arguments of event handlers, callbacks, etc.

Note that in the expression `chart.scales.x`, `x` is the *id* of the axis. The id of the default horizontal axis is `x`; if you define a new axis in `options`, e.g.,

```js
options:{
    scales:{
        "x-axis-on-top": {.....} // new x scale properties
    }
}
```

then the id of this axis is `x-axis-on-top` and the minimum value for instance can be obtained as

```js
const x2Min = chart.scales["x-axis-on-top"].min;
```

Comment: So `xMin = chart.scales.x.min` or `chart.scales['x'].min`, and `xMax = chart.scales.x.max` or `chart.scales['x'].max`; y-axis is analogous.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with numerical data you can use the Math.min and Math.max methods:

```
const xAxisData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

let xMin = Math.min(...xAxisData);

let xMax = Math.max(...xAxisData);
```

Array of objects comprised of x and y values:

```
const yourData = yourChartData.data.dataset[0].data;

let xMin = Math.min(...yourData.map(abscissa => abscissa.x));

let xMax = Math.max(...yourData.map(abscissa => abscissa.x));

let yMin = Math.min(...yourData.map(ordinate => ordinate.y));

let yMax = Math.max(...yourData.map(ordinate => ordinate.y));
```

Comment: That gives me the minimum or maximum of the underlying data.  That may or may not be, and in general will not be, the same as the boundaries of the axis.